# Is there a way to perform all Modernizr tests all at once?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, compatibility, modernizr

I'm new to Modernizr and I'm just looking for a simple way to check for overall browser compatibility. I've generated a Modernizr script to test for only the most essential components of my web application, which is highly dependent on HTML5, CSS3, and modern JavaScript methods. Is there a way to run all of these tests simultaneously? Looking over the documentation, I see plenty of ways to test each feature one by one, but I'm not seeing a way to do it all at once. I'm hoping to do something like this:

**Pseudocode**

```
if (Modernizr.testAll()) {
  // Load site
} else {
  // Redirect to compatibility page
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that all the tests are stored as booleans directly in the `Modernizr` object, so if you're building an application with a lot of feature dependencies and you want to test them all at once, use this:

```
var supported = true;
for (var feature in Modernizr) {
  if (typeof Modernizr[feature] === "boolean" && Modernizr[feature] == false) {
    supported = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought recently that a `Modernizr.__all__` or something could be useful – especially with the new `Modernizr.on()` API: `Modernizr.on('__all__', function () { /* all async tests have run */ });`… what do you think @David?

Comment: @StuCox: I think that would be great – it would definitely be useful in my situation.

Comment: This is not working well for me: it only loops over a small subset of all tests.

Comment: I posted this a year ago...it's possible that the Modernizr object has changed. I would suggest looking at it and seeing if you can modify my code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I came up with the following code:

```
for (var feature in Modernizr) 
{
    if (typeof Modernizr[feature] === "boolean")
    {
        console.log("Modernizr_" + feature + ": " +Modernizr[feature]);

        for (var subFeature in Modernizr[feature])
        {
            if (typeof Modernizr[feature][subFeature] === "boolean")
            {
                console.log("Modernizr_" + feature + "_"+ subFeature + ": " + Modernizr[feature]);          
            }
        }
    }


}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way that works for me and all in one line

`Object.values(Modernizr).indexOf(false) === -1`

Comment: It might be better if you try to explain your answer a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I personally struggled a lot with this. But finally found an answer at the end of the day. You can use my code below, it will show the full list Modernizr features and their values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function ListAllMOdernizrFeatures() {


            var TotalString = "Modernizr features<br><br>";
            var arrModernizrFeatures = new Array();


            for (var feature in Modernizr) {

                if (typeof Modernizr[feature] === "boolean") {
                    console.log("Modernizr_" + feature + ": " + Modernizr[feature]);
                    arrModernizrFeatures.push("Modernizr." + feature + ": " + Modernizr[feature])

                    for (var subFeature in Modernizr[feature]) {
                        var ModernizrFeature = Modernizr[feature];
                        if (typeof ModernizrFeature[subFeature] === "boolean") {
                            arrModernizrFeatures.push("Modernizr." + feature + subFeature + ": " + ModernizrFeature[subFeature]);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            arrModernizrFeatures.sort(); // in lexicographical order

            for (var PropertyIterator = 0; PropertyIterator < arrModernizrFeatures.length; PropertyIterator++) {
                TotalString += PropertyIterator + 1 + ". " + arrModernizrFeatures[PropertyIterator] + "<br>";
            };
            document.getElementById("ListFeatures").innerHTML = TotalString;
        }

        setTimeout(ListAllMOdernizrFeatures, 100);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern Javascript (ECMAScript 2017), you can utilise the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method like so:

```
if (Object.values(Modernizr).indexOf(false) !== -1) {
    console.log('Update your browser (and avoid IE/Edge )')
}
```

`Object.values` will extract all of the test results from `Modernizr` into an array, and then `indexOf(false)` will test to see if any of the array items are false (i.e. test failed).

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code if you want to display all feature detections in the browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Modernizr Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.0.6/modernizr.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Feature Detection</h1>
<div id="feature-detection-result">

</div>
<script>
    var features = Object.keys(Modernizr);
    features = features.sort();

    features.forEach(feature => {
        if (typeof Modernizr[feature] === "boolean") {
            var element = document.createElement('p');
            element.innerHTML = feature + ' ' + Modernizr[feature];
            document.getElementById('feature-detection-result').appendChild(
                element
            );
            console.log(feature, Modernizr[feature]);
        }
        }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code if you want to display all feature detections in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Modernizr Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.0.6/modernizr.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Feature Detection</h1>
<div id="feature-detection-result">

</div>
<script>
    var features = Object.keys(Modernizr);
    features = features.sort();

    features.forEach(feature => {
        if (typeof Modernizr[feature] === "boolean") {
            var element = document.createElement('p');
            element.innerHTML = feature + ' ' + Modernizr[feature];
            document.getElementById('feature-detection-result').appendChild(element);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```